# how theme/template connected/related to each other

Tags: theming, entities, 8

for example, I have:

1. module id: `module_id` (file: `module_id.info.yml`)
2. FieldType ID: `FieldTypeID` (file: /src/plugin/Field/FieldType/`FieldType.php`)
3. FieldWidget: `FieldDefaultWidget` (file: /src/plugin/Field/FieldWidget/`FieldDefaultWidget`.php)
4. FieldFormatter: `FieldDefaultFormatter` (file: /src/plugin/Field/FieldWidget/`FieldDefaultFormatter`.php)

and inside my field formatter:

```
public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $elements = [];
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      $elements[$delta] = [
        '#theme' => 'my_field',
        '#type' => 'markup',
        // etc...
      ];
    }

    return $elements;
  }
```

5. I have file: `my_field`.module

with function:

```
function my_field_theme() {
  return array(
    'location_field' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'x' => NULL,
        'y' => NULL,
        'z' => NULL,
      ),
      'template' => 'my_field',
    ),
  );
}
```

6. and I have template file: /templates/`my_field`.html.twig

as simple as:

```
<section class="class">
  <h2>name</h2>
  <div class="cls" data-x="x" data-y="y" data-z="z">content</div>
</section>
```

with that, seems like i can't see my template, which i don't have any idea why?

how is theme or template name relate with the filename (or ID or anything)? - how are they connected each other?

what is the rule for that?

Thank you,

AnD

Answer (score 1):

If your code is only in one module with the name module_id, then in
5. the file should be named `module_id.module` and the function `module_id_theme()`

Comment: I have multiple module which will use this field type - will it still applicable?
anyway, i will try and see if it works!

Comment: and in my: my field formatter should i change: '#theme' => 'my_field', into module_id?

Comment: hmm apparently it doesnt work